# Large amount of DecryptRequest request by DataProc for data in Cloud Storage protected by custom managed HSM key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-kms

We have transactional data in Cloud Storage encrypted with Custom Managed HSM key and when user submit jobs , a dataproc cluster spins and process some analytics on the data stored in the Cloud Storage.
The data is a transactional data partitioned on a per day basis and stored in parquet file ( a single file per day ) format . Every thing works good but behind the scenes there are extremely large number of calls calling Decrypt operation.
We have already increased the Quota to 250K operations per minute but it seems we are simply reaching this threshold . Currently we are forced to reduce the number of parallel jobs that we can process severely impacting our SLA and since we reached the Quota of KMS requests , other processing products like BIG Query whose data is also encrypted  , fails to perform its operations , resulting request failures .

I am getting exception with message --> **"Project 'XXX' exceeded limit for metric cloudkms.googleapis.com/hsm_symmetric_requests."**

When looked at the logs , I could see enormous number of requests

```
request: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.kms.v1.DecryptRequest"
name: <KeyPath>
}
```

from cloud storage account **"service-XXXX@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com"**

I can understand storage account asking for decryption of data but 250K requests per minute (our current limit) for a single job which might be operating maximum 300 to 400 files is too high in my view.

Did somehow faced this kind of challenge ? How it can be handled as we planned to use large number of parallel jobs meaning there will be a need for quite a higher amount of "hsm_symmetric_requests" request quota. Also would be great if some one can explain the behavior .

Comment: Keep in mind that each 4K data block is encrypted with a different key (DEK). The DEK is encrypted with the KEK which is encrypted with your CMEK.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the explanation . Just figured out from https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/hsm#known_limitations. Also based on some base assumptions on my needs , the computations are resulted in 478  Million requests  which definitely an insane number.

Now i am asking myself how CMEK and big data are working together. Based on  explanations in the google docs , enormous number of decrypt quota is needed .

Comment: Unless you need the high security that CMEK offers, use Google managed keys and KMS. In the encryption world, 478 million requests is nothing. A somewhat bigger issue is the delays that CMEK adds.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply . Will discuss the need for CMEK with our security officer . 478M are the amount of requests per minute if we operate for 20 parallel requests. This not only adds large additional costs but decent latency . Currently after lot of ping pong with google support we could able to increase the quota to 300K and reducing the parallel jobs to 1.  But thanks for confirming that these numbers are not large taking the context into consideration .

Comment: @JohnHanley I have an extension question. We have the same data in BigQuery and the dataset is protected with another HSM key. We perform significantly large computations on that data . Fortunately we are not seeing the same behavior. The number of calls are significantly less. Large number of calls onto storage is understandable seeing the explanation on HSM but its not clear why its not happening in BigQuery . Any insights ?

Comment: I do not know the answer. BigQuery uses its own storage engine. I have a feeling the difference is due to key caching and the size of data blocks. There is a BigQuery expert (Mikhail Berlyant) that visits SO. Create a new question tagged with `google-bigquery` so he will see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnHanley for the explanations . It seems using HSM keys might not be a great decision particularly with big data stored in cloud storage and definitely it comes with a price tag. I will approach my security officer to understand the need for CMEK and will take the next steps . What still puzzles me is why google set such a low limit  60000 requests per minute when each 16Kb needs a call to decrypt and why its so hard to convince the google support to increase the Quota. Regarding BQ i will create another question ,

Comment: @JohnHanley Today i had a discussion with out security officer and i was pointed to the [article](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/?utm_medium=et&utm_source=google.com%2Fcloud&utm_campaign=resources&utm_content=resource_card#data_encryption_keys_key_encryption_keys_and_googles_key_management_service) .

Comment: According to this article, data in the storage is split into chunks and each chunk is encrypted by DEK and DEK is encrypted by KEK managed by KMS and this data chuck can be quite a bigger size as per [link]( https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption#encryption_at_the_storage_system_layer). Unfortunately i am confused now if the 16KB limitation comes in this scenario . Do you have any insights for me .

Comment: Most applications are designed for file systems and not for blob storage. In order to have large blobs the application needs to write large blobs AND the encryption system must support large blobs. HSM is 16 KB, KSM is 64 KB, Google managed keys multiple GB. Since you are using CMEK, your blob size is 16 KB.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley .I think the encryption size limitations comes only when we are directly using the HSM key to encrypt data . But as posted in the above link , the data in storage is chunked and encrypted by DEK and these chunks can be several GB and the DEK used to encrypt the chunks are wrapped by KEK . The data in my storage each file ranges from  100MB to 400MB blobs . This is where i am getting confused and difficult to accept the fact that 16KB limitation is the reason for the High Decrypt request.